# Why does NSWindow become first responder when unbinding an object

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, becomefirstresponder

I manually bind the value of a NSTextView to a property of an object. When I call unbind, the window becomes first responder ... Why?

I don't want that!

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't a lot of information here, but you might want to check the responder chain to see if the window is next in line and being passed the focus.